# "Getter and Setter methods for all the member variables" what does it mean..?

Tags: java

In a project I want, Getter and Setter methods for all the member variables. how can i do this? and what does this mean?
the following is the code where i want to use getter and setter method

```
public abstract class Connection {
int previousReading;
int currentReading;
float[] slabs;
public Connection(int currentReading, int previousReading,float slabs[])
{
    this.currentReading = currentReading;
    this.previousReading = previousReading;
    this.slabs = slabs;
}
public abstract float computeBill();

}
```

Comment: Instance fields should be `private` (as an example of the tighest access control) to prevent unsolicited modification. A "setter" provides a means by which an outside party may supply a value to the properties; a "getter" returns the current value of the property.  You can forego supplying a "setter" and the value becomes readonly

Comment: Once you learn what they are, you can usually save yourself some typing by having your IDE generate them for you.  IntelliJ and Eclipse, for example, each have some menu-driven way to "generate getters and setters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired design, you need to follow the **Encapsulation** concept (also known as '**Data hiding**'), which is one of the basic OOP concepts.
What Encapsulation means is basically, wrapping the variables in accessors methods (called getters and setters) in order for them to be hidden from other classes.
The variables can be accessed only through those getters and setters and not directly.

### In order to achieve this:

1. Declare the variables of a class as private.
2. Provide public setter and getter methods to modify and view the
   variables values.

### Example:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int age;

public String getName() {
 return this.name;
}

public String setName(final String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
 return this.age;
}

public String setAge(final String age) {
this.age = age;
}
}
```

### Why do we need Encapsulation for?

#### Using Encapsulation we can:

1. Control the allowed accessors of a variable (by declaring the access level as protected/public).
2. Limit the values that can be stored in a field.
3. Perform an action when a field is modified (perform validation, trigger an event, call another method).
4. Change the data representation (convert the input data type).
5. Provide thread safety using synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Connection {

private int previousReading;
private int currentReading;
private float[] slabs;
public Connection(int currentReading, int previousReading,float slabs[])
{
    this.currentReading = currentReading;
    this.previousReading = previousReading;
    this.slabs = slabs;
}
public int getPreviousReading() {
    return previousReading;
}
public void setPreviousReading(int previousReading) {
    this.previousReading = previousReading;
}
public int getCurrentReading() {
    return currentReading;
}
public void setCurrentReading(int currentReading) {
    this.currentReading = currentReading;
}
public float[] getSlabs() {
    return slabs;
}
public void setSlabs(float[] slabs) {
    this.slabs = slabs;
}
```

}

Comment: This is the getter and setter you are looking for

Comment: Please explain a bit of your code. It would be helpful and more clear

Comment: It means your local attributes shoud be private because it cannot be accessed outside the class and the setMethods are for setting the value and the getMethods are for getting the value. Its a kind of pojo class but in your case its not a pojo class because it is not following certain rules. Go through this tutorial as it can have some idea for you https://www.javatpoint.com/q/3019/what-is-the-difference-between-javabean-and-pojo-class